# Text not showing up on Gimp 2.8

Tags: gimp, text

[image: My Text not showing up]

I am trying to enter text on Gimp 2.8.  However, when I try, a cursor just moves across the screen and no text is entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding text, ensure it is the top most layer. If the text layer is below any other layer, use the raise layer button in the layer dialog to arrange it at the top. Alternatively go to Layer-stack-Raise layer to move the layer.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure to remove the layer. Then you want to double click the "A" icon then change the color of the text. This should work.