# Text Not Showing Up In Gimp (Mac)

Tags: gimp, text, mac

I'm trying to add some text to a moderately complex layout, but the text tool is malfunctioning -- everything shows as blank no matter what I type.

I have checked:

- Foreground color shows reasonable contrast (tested with a Paint action)
- No other layers obscuring the view (the accepted solution in [Text not showing up on Gimp 2.8](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/text-not-showing-up-on-gimp-2-8))
- Same issue with both system and user fonts
- Font size is reasonable

I was able to reproduce the problem on a new 640x640 image with a single white layer

In addition, when I restart Gimp, the .xcf file cannot be loaded

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Tech support questions are generally off-topic because users here don't have access to your computer or set up.  Probably best to check out the various GIMP forums in future for such questions.  If there is a bug or something, then it's likely other people have had the same problem.

Comment: Also note that GIMP 2.8 is outdated. Better to get the most recent version instead.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem appears to be that I had both Gimp 2.8 and Gimp 2.10 installed on the system.  Problem did not reoccur once I made sure to sandbox 2.8.